# How to smoothen a closed polyline shape in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, dlib, smoothing

I am trying to select a custom ROI as shown in the figure below:

[image: ROI to be drawn]

I am using dlib to detect and facial landmarks, now that I have facial landmark points, how can I draw above shown mask below eyes?

[image: Facial Landmarks coordinates calculated by dlib]

For now, I have been able to draw ROI using some approximations based upon facial landmark coordinates and joining the coordinates using polyline function of OpenCV as shown in the above image. My results so far look like this now:

[image]

Q: how can I make it smooth as shown in the first figure?
I have been recommended to use Fourier Descriptors for this but I can't figure out how can I use Fourier Descriptors for this problem.

Comment: thanks it works. I have done it using openexr